# Get Element by Id and set the value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, default-value

I have a JavaScript function to which I pass a parameter. The parameter represents the id of an element (a hidden field) in my web page. I want to change the value of this element.

```
function myFunc(variable) {
  var s = document.getElementById(variable);
  s.value = 'New value'
}
```

When I do this, I get an error that the value cannot be set because the object is null. But I know the object is not null because I see it in the HTML code generated by the browser.

Anyway, I tried the following code to debug

```
function myFunc(variable) {
  var x = variable;
  var y = 'This-is-the-real-id'
  alert(x + ', ' + y)
  var s = document.getElementById(x);
  s.value = 'New value'
}
```

When the alert message shows up, both parameters are the same, but I still get the error. But everything works fine when I do

```
  var s = document.getElementById('This-is-the-real-id');
  s.value = 'New value'
```

How can I fix this?

The element for which I am setting the value is a  hidden field and the id is set dynamically, as the page loads. I have tried added this in the *$(document).ready* function, but it did not work.

Comment: Let's see where you call the function (which, judging from the code you've provided, doesn't have a name).

Comment: what is variable? And how do you call the unnamed function?

Comment: When you do a diagnostic `alert()` or `console.log()` in cases like this, you should **always** wrap values with some marker characters so you can tell whether there are stray space characters in the strings. So: `alert("[" + x + "], [" + y + "]");`

Comment: Please show an example of this happening at jsfiddle.net - what you are asking doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If *myFunc(variable)* is executed before the textarea is rendered to the page, you will get the null exception error.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunc(variable) {
                var s = document.getElementById(variable);
                s.value = "new value";
            }
            myFunc("id1");
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <textarea id="id1"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
<!-- Error message: Cannot set property 'value' of null -->
```

So, make sure your textarea does exist on the page, and then call *myFunc*. You can use the *window.onload* or *$(document).ready* function.

Comment: I create the hidden field, and then create the button which executes the function that sets the value of the hidden field. However, the id is set dynamically. I tried added this function in the $(document).ready function but the same issue arises.

Comment: @jpo If the id is set dynamically, you also should make sure that myFunc is called after the id is set. You can try to call myFunc in the function which sets the id.

Comment: My code look like this @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.myfield, new{id = "myId"}) <input type="button" onclick="javascript: myFunc(myID)" value="button"/>.

Comment: The function is only called when the button is clicked and this only happens after the page loads. How else can I ensure that everything happens before the button is clicked?

Comment: @jpo In onclick="javascript: myFunc(myID)", myID should be wrapped by single quotes.

Comment: @jpo When will you set the id of textarea? Before page loads or after page loads? Before the button is clicked or after the button is clicked?

Comment: It is set before the button is clicked.

Comment: @jpo It's weird, is myID wrapped by single quotes? Or your id is not set successfully. Have you checked the id with the web developer tool like firebug? Does it exist?

Answer (score 27):

Given

```html
<div id="This-is-the-real-id"></div>
```

then

```javascript
function setText(id, newvalue) {
  var s = document.getElementById(id);
  s.innerHTML = newvalue;
}

window.onload = function() { // Or window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setText("This-is-the-real-id", "Hello there");
}
```

will do what you want

---

Given

```html
<input id="This-is-the-real-id" type="text" value="">
```

then

```javascript
function setValue(id, newvalue) {
  var s = document.getElementById(id);
  s.value = newvalue;
}

window.onload = function() {
  setValue("This-is-the-real-id", "Hello there");
}
```

will do what you want

```js
function setContent(id, newvalue) {
  var s = document.getElementById(id);
  if (s.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") 
    s.value = newvalue;
  else 
    s.innerHTML = newvalue;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setContent("This-is-the-real-id-div", "Hello there");
  setContent("This-is-the-real-id-input", "Hello there");
})
```

```html
<div id="This-is-the-real-id-div"></div>
<input id="This-is-the-real-id-input" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought. But my id and set dynamically. But I used the same idea. But when I function is called, the document cannot find the element with the specified id

Comment: We need to see the html and the event handler (onclick or whatever)

Answer (score 6):

No answer brought up the possibility of using `.setAttribute()` in addition to `.value()`:

```
document.getElementById('some-input').value="1337";
document.getElementById('some-input').setAttribute("value", "1337");
```

This addendum actually changes the content of the value in the pages source, which in turn makes the value update `form.reset()`-proof.

Comment: Rude? Or did I just miss an SO rule here?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function updateTextarea(element)
        {
            document.getElementById(element).innerText = document.getElementById("ment").value;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text"
           value="Enter your text here."
           id = "ment"
           style = " border: 1px solid grey; margin-bottom: 4px;"
           onKeyUp="updateTextarea('myDiv')" />
    <br>

    <textarea id="myDiv" ></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

For each element type, you can use a specific attribute to set value.

E.g.:

```html
<div id="theValue1"></div>
window.document.getElementById("theValue1").innerText = "value div";

<input id="theValue2"></input>
window.document.getElementById("theValue2").value = "value input";
```

[You can try the example here!](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbVvvW?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like below. It will work...

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function displayResult(element)
        {
            document.getElementById(element).value = 'hi';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="myTextarea" cols="20">
        BYE
    </textarea>
    <br>

    <button type="button" onclick="displayResult('myTextarea')">Change</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers are bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you call your JavaScript function.

Your code is like so:

```html
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: myFunc(myID)" value="button"/>
```

*myID* should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: The `javascript:` label is completely unnecessary