# How to set password and username in javascript for a form placed inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have put a login modal using bootstrap 3 as explained in the link

http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/modal/

In the JavaScript code how to set the username and password to a particular value for the login form.
I am still learning html and css. I don't know much about javascript.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649173/javascript-get-element-by-id-and-set-the-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[name="username"]').val('user');
$('input[name="password"]').val('password')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sp5fcaLm/

Although I'm not sure setting password directly is the best idea.

Comment: thankyou :) Although i did validation using php i just wanted to know the method!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- The form is placed inside the body of modal -->
            <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript code:

```
$('#loginModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#username').val('example@gmail.com');
      $('#password').val('123456');
});
```

Remember include twitter-bootstrap. Its [here](http://getbootstrap.com/)