# How to get element by id in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I tried all the possible solutions to get the value of an element by id, but it did not work. I am using ASP.NET, I have searched for the controls and I know that the server changes the id of the `TextBox1`, so we use the `clientID`. But when I write console.log(data1), I get nothing or empty space.

```
var data1 = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').textContent;
var data1 = document.getElementById("<%=MainContent_TextBox1.ClientID %>").value;
```

This is the ASPX code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

And this the JS code:

```
 var data1 = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').textContent;
```

In the console, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input and its reference in the master file!

`console.log(data1);` appears in the console as empty place.

If anyone knows another way or why it is not working, please tell me.

Comment: Is your JavaScript running after the page has been loaded?

Comment: No, it actually runs at the same time ..onload

Comment: @tymeJV how to make sure that JavaScript running after the page has been loaded?!

Comment: Put your JavaScript at the bottom of your page.

Comment: its an external file, but thank you i tried another way and it works just fine now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Id of server controls gets changed and is appended with content place holder id so a very easy solution is to set a property `ClientIDMode="static"` on server controls. By setting this id of control will remain same and will not get changed so you will find it by `getElementById` in javascript.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this to get master page control value in content page. document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("Textbox1").ClientID %>'). If it's same page then you should be able to use directly document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").

Comment: i don't get what u said could u please elaborate more. why would i use the master here!

Comment: You need to use Master to find the control that resides in master page.

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Javascript - this needs to b in the html after the control you are trying to find
    var data1 = document.getElementById('<%= Master.FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID %>').value;
    
    // jQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= Master.FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID %>').val();
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

1.You may be having the same problem as in this question:

[Javascript Get Element by Id and set the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649173/javascript-get-element-by-id-and-set-the-value)

If the page hasn't loaded that element yet before your javascript runs getElementById will return null.

"So, make sure your [element] does exist in the page, and then call [getElementById], you can use window.onload or $(document).ready function."

2.The error: 
    `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input and its reference in the master file` may be caused by a missing braket or other formatting error. Double check everything is written correctly.

Comment: It might help if you could provide the JS and Html files

Comment: You should really provide the entirety of the code block so that we can check code progression/syntax. There are too many possible errors given your info.